# Error occurs when I Migrate the database using Rake; db:migrate command results to NoMethodError;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, dbmigrate

using ruby version : 1.9.3

config/database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

NoMethodError pops up when I use the command:

```
   bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

[image: This error pops up when I try to ise bundle exec rake db:migrate command]

Full Trace log is as follows:

[image]

Comment: rails version? ruby version? sample app on github that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Rails : 3.2.3
Ruby :  1.9.3
Github: https://github.com/ralstonJ/demo_app

Comment: I don't see any migration files in your demo_app on Github. Do you have any migrations in local that you are trying to migrate with `rake db:migrate` command?

Comment: `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string` is the command I used before `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: Can you share the code from `config/database.yml` file. Add it in the question.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I have included the `config/database.yml` now.

Comment: Solved the issue. It was the gemfile